# How to make this code in one line in my Makefile

Tags: linux, bash, makefile

Have you a idea to do theses action in one line ?

```
PROJECT_NAME    := $(if $(CI),$(CI_PROJECT_NAME),$(PROJECT_NAME))
PROJECT_NAME    := `echo $(PROJECT_NAME) | tr A-Z a-z`
```

Comment: No, I just think that I can make it in one line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just substitute the assignment in the first command for the `PROJECT_NAME` variable in the second command.

Also,  use `$(shell cmd)` instead of backquotes to run shell commands.

```
PROJECT_NAME := $(shell echo $(if $(CI),$(CI_PROJECT_NAME),$(PROJECT_NAME)) | tr A-Z a-z)
```

Comment: @NicolasS. Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Answer (score 3):

```
PROJECT_NAME    := `echo $(if $(CI),$(CI_PROJECT_NAME),$(PROJECT_NAME)) | tr A-Z a-z`
```

However, I am sorry to hear you have a shortage of new-line characters and need to conserve them. I have a ready supply of tens and could send you as many as you need. (If you are not using ASCII, I would have to check what I have in stock. Some numbers are harder to obtain than others.)

You may also want to use `shell` to cause the echo command to be executed once during the setting of `PROJECT_NAME` instead of every time it is used in a command:

```
PROJECT_NAME    := $(shell echo $(if $(CI),$(CI_PROJECT_NAME),$(PROJECT_NAME)) | tr A-Z a-z)
```